# Compute Power Delay Profile (PDP) from Delay Spread

Tags: matlab, power-spectral-density, delay

I have data pertaining to channel obtained from measurements. In order to make use of this data, I need to convert it into a form as follows:

```
    ChanMod.PDP_dB = [-2.5   0 -12.8  -10    -25.2  -16; % Average power [dB]
                      0 300*10^-9 8900*10^-9 12900*10^-9 17100*10^-9 20000*10^-9]; % delay (s)
    ChanMod.normH = sqrt(sum(10.^(ChanMod.PDP_dB(1,:)/10)));
```

However, the data from the measurements is in the form of `Delay spread vs distance`. I am not sure how to determine the `power delay profile` from the `Delay spread` data.

I am new to signal processing. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Not at all. Delay Spread is just a *statistical* number that says something about how far the PDP is spread out. You can't reconstruct the PDP from that.

It's basically the same as wanting to reproduce the exact height distribution of a group of people when all you know is the variance of height.

Comment: I wish the community would be more generous with good answers. +1 yours as it surely answers the question yet got no feedback.